# Java terminating before running code after nested if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

SOLVED -- learned a lesson in looking for dumb errors along with looking for the programming mistake when trouble-shooting.

I am a student 1 month into comp-sci 1 so my knowledge is in the slim to none category. Below is my code for a program that takes the user input of 3 test scores and finds the average and tells the user the grade. The program compiles with no errors however after the if statement verifying that the 3rd score entered is in the valid range the program terminates without proceeding to the following block of nested if else statements. I've searched but can't figure out the problem, hoping to find help here from you fine folks, thanks.

```
grade1_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first test score.");
grade1 = Integer.parseInt(grade1_string);

if (grade1 >= 0 && grade1 <= 110)//allowing for 10 pts extra credit
{
  grade2_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second test score.");
  grade2 = Integer.parseInt(grade2_string);

  if (grade2 >= 0 && grade2 <= 110)
  {
     grade3_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the third test score.");
     grade3 = Integer.parseInt(grade3_string);

     if (grade3 >= 0 && grade3 <= 110)
     { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"calcuating...");

        avrgGrade = (float)(grade1 * grade2 * grade3) / 3;

        if (avrgGrade >= 0 && avrgGrade < 60)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, your average is " + avrgGrade +
                                              ", an F");
        }
        else if (avrgGrade >= 60 && avrgGrade < 70)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, your average is " + avrgGrade +
                                              ", a D");
        }
        else if (avrgGrade >= 70 && avrgGrade < 80)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not bad, your average is " + avrgGrade +
                                              ", a C");
        }
        else if (avrgGrade >= 80 && avrgGrade < 90)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Pretty good, your average is " + avrgGrade +
                                              ", a B");
        }
        else if (avrgGrade >= 90 && avrgGrade <= 110)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Way to go, your average is " + avrgGrade +
                                              ", an A");
        }
     }
     else
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is not a valid test score, " +
                                           "please run the program again to " +
                                           "calculate your average.");
     }  
  }
  else 
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is not a valid test score, please " +
                                        "run the program again to calculate your " +
                                        "average.");
  }
```

At the end is a 3rd else with the same message about not entering a valid score(couldn't get the formatting right)

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use the debugger in your IDE.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you post your code on SO, try running through each line and making sure it makes sense, and if necessary printing out each line. That way you catch stupid mistakes instead of us finding them for you. On the topic of stupid mistakes, the formula for average of three numbers is (a+b+c)/3, not (a * b * c)/3.

For example when you need the average of the tests, I am pretty sure you want:

```
int avrgGrade = (float)(grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
```

not

```
int avrgGrade = (float)(grade1 * grade2 * grade3) / 3;
```

That will solve your issue. Also, I don't know where you are initializing all the variables you use, but you might is well initialize them where you define them.

Comment: Oh man, that's embarrassing. I was so focused on finding where I messed up the programming that I didn't even look at the (mis)calculation that I entered when I initially wrote it last night at 3am. Thank you for your help, in the future I will definitely check all parts of the code before posting.